# android MediaPlayer to play online(external) audio

Tags: android, audio, mp3, android-mediaplayer

I use this code to play online mp3 audio when I click on button but it doesn't work.

```
public void play(View v) throws IllegalStateException, IOException{ 
    MediaPlayer em2 =MediaPlayer.create(this, Uri.parse("https://ia801005.us.archive.org/22/items/sslamweb.blogspot.com_201308/Maher%20Zain%20-%20Hold%20My%20Hand%20-%20Official%20Lyrics%20Video.mp3"));
    em2.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);  
    em2.prepare();
    em2.start();        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating the `MediaPlayer` using `create`, which calls `prepare` for you already. Don't call `prepare` again.

```
public void play(View v) throws IllegalStateException, IOException{ 
    MediaPlayer em2 = MediaPlayer.create(this, Uri.parse("https://ia801005.us.archive.org/22/items/sslamweb.blogspot.com_201308/Maher%20Zain%20-%20Hold%20My%20Hand%20-%20Official%20Lyrics%20Video.mp3"));
    em2.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    em2.start();        
}
```

In the future, it would help to see logcat output of the error.

Answer (score 0):

import android.media.AudioManager;

```
android.media.MediaPlayer mediaplayer;
                        mediaplayer = new android.media.MediaPlayer();
                        mediaplayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                        try {

                            mediaplayer.setDataSource("https://ia801005.us.archive.org/22/items/sslamweb.blogspot.com_201308/Maher%20Zain%20-%20Hold%20My%20Hand%20-%20Official%20Lyrics%20Video.mp3");
                            mediaplayer.prepare();
                        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (SecurityException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        mediaplayer.start();
```

Enjoy.......